# CSS(3?) : Create background with rectangle center bright

Tags: css

I am working on a project where I'm trying to *almost* make a login screen looking like [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/1945593-Login-Home-Screen).
Except the blackish opacity is around the login and the brighter area is the center where the inputs are.

*Any lead on what I could do ?*

Here are some thoughts :

- I'd rather not have to load two times my bg img ;)
- And I don't think using a modal is the key...
- I thought about using a gradient but it seems rather non-responsive and hard to do (or maybe I'm not seeing this correctly).

Note to yourself : I'll prabably do a codepen with the result, so people can reuse it =)

Comment: And where is the problem? Its just a page with a background and a div with another background (or transparent) and a gradient. Post a codepen with the code you have so far.

Comment: Using a page with a background and a div with another background causes to load two bg. 
The issue of the gradient is its (if I see this correctly) non-responsiveness.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you want to do, but you could maybe take a look into [css filters](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp) and do something like this:

```
#image1{
    filter:brightness(200%);
```

}

Keep in mind that these filters are not widely supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS blending modes. Your main container (`<body>`) would have a large background image. And for the modal:

```
.modal {
    background: purple;
    mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}
```

But note that it's not supported by all browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode

A nice article on blending modes: http://alistapart.com/article/blending-modes-demystified